# Show a random element on hover, Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm looking to have a random paragraph element display each time I mouse over the logo, and hide again when the mouse leaves.

Here's the HTML for the paragraphs and the logo:

```
<div>
<p class="quote" >ryan is a champion at indesign</p>
<p class="quote">ryan is not a champion at javascript</p>
<p class="quote">ryan likes ramen</p>
</div>

<a href="#"><img id="logo" src="../_blog/_assets/_logo_icons/_logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
```

This script is the closest I've found so far that fulfills this:

```
$('p.quote').hide();

var quotes = $('p.quote');
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);

$('#logo').hover(function(){
    quotes.eq(rand).toggle();

    });
```

Unfortunately this only displays the same quote every time unless I refresh the page. Any other suggestions?

Thanks
Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the line starting `var rand` into the hover function instead of outside it.

Then change:

```
quotes.eq(rand).toggle();
```

To:

```
quotes.hide().eq(rand).show();
```

You will also need to modify the .hover() so that it hides the quote when they stop hovering.

Here is the full code:

```
var quotes = $('p.quote');

$('#logo').hover(
  function() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
    quotes.hide().eq(rand).show();
  },
  function() {
    quotes.hide()
  }
);
```

Comment: If I move var rand into the function then sometimes more than one quote will pop up, and will not hide again when my mouse leaves.

Comment: @Ryan Sorry, I was in the middle of editing, the full answer is now there.

Comment: Ok, this seems to be working well. I wrote something a little different to hide the quote, but your script is a bit nicer.

Here's the full script:

    $('p.quote').hide();
              
    var quotes = $('p.quote');
        
        
    $('#logo').mouseover(function(){
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
         quotes.hide().eq(rand).show();
          
    });
    $('#logo').mouseleave(function(){
       quotes.hide();
    });
        
    });

Comment: hover() is identical to using separate mouseenter (NOT mouseover, don't use that) mouseleave functions, so you might as well use it.

Answer (score 1):

Move `var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);` inside your hover-handler, like this:

```
$('#logo').hover(function(){
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
    quotes.eq(rand).toggle();

    });
```

This way, it will update your rand every time

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wEnAW/7/